# How to add an onload event to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code is,

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>onclick test</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var googleWindow = window.open('http://www.google.com');
           window.onload = change;
           function change(){
            alert('Hello');
           }
        </script>
</html>
```

The above code is working fine. It calls the change function when the window is loading. I am trying add onload event to the googleWindow but it is not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>onclick test</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var googleWindow = window.open('http://www.google.com');
           googleWindow.onload = change;
           function change(){
            alert("Hello');
           }
        </script>
</html>
```

How do i add an event to the googleWindow?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onload event only triggers a function that is loaded *in that window*, so you can't really do that. However, if you can control the content of the new window you're opening (i.e. if you'd open a window that displays some content of your own) then you could place an onload handler in the page that opens in that window, and then the called function could interact with the opener window via 'window.opener', e.g. if you have two files '1.html' and '2.html' then you can have:

### 1.html

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('2.html')">Open '2.html'</a>
```

### 2.html

```
<head><script>
window.opener.alert("this alert is displayed by the '1.html' window");
</script></head>
```

In the above, after you click the link in the first window, the second window will open (probably in a new tab in your browser) and immediately after it gets opened you'll see the alert displayed in the first window (i.e. the first tab)

PS
Oh, and as Rory pointed out in his answer, you must absolutely have the files on the same domain

Answer (score 8):

You cannot add an event to a window in another domain.